# Secure deletion of part of a file

Tags: security, file-management

I have moved my passwords to a password manager. Previously they were in a sheet of a multi-sheet Excel file. Is it possible for me to securely delete *that sheet* in the file but leave the rest alone?

Answer (score 1):

The best Way to securely delete that sheet (from all my experience in recovery of data) is to actually take all the data (in the sheet you are deleting) and rewrite it with random data. Save it. Close, open and then delete that sheet.

Then you will have re-written the data you don't want recovered.